# Calculate a numeric score from a Google Form submission using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to calculate a numeric score from a google form submission using google apps script.

I have a form with 20 questions, each question response corresponds to a numeric score.

**The Google form**

*Q1 = some text with question*

```
Q1 resultant dropdown box

    0 = option 1 
    1 = option 2
    2 = option 3
```

*Q2 = some more text*

```
Q2 resultant dropdown box

    0 = option a 
    1 = option b 
    2 = option c
```

So if the person filling the form chooses say Q1 (option 2) = 1 then Q2 (option c) = 2 the resulting numeric score for that form session would be 3.

I'm looking to then store this value next to a date and time of form filled in a corresponding google sheet.

Could someone please point me in a direction of a working form/sheet that does something close to this.

I've been searching for examples from the web for ages, but am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Please post JSON.stringify(e.namedValues) and JSON.stringify(e.values) in your question.  You can get these from the event object of your onFormSubmit trigger

Comment: I'm not sure how to get that information MetaMan, sorry. I was hoping to do some thing like this in google forms, https://www.clinical-partners.co.uk/for-adults/depression/a-test-for-depression/depression-test-results/results, along with saving the data in sheets, so it can be graphed. I just don't know where to start. I could achieve this with PHP and a MySQL database, but this seems like overkill.

Comment: This is a link to the questions with ratings and how to calculate the end result. https://www.ismanet.org/doctoryourspirit/pdfs/Beck-Depression-Inventory-BDI.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that you know the numeric score of every answer. Based on that, you can easily develop a trigger that calculates the numeric score of the form response. First you would need an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that fires at every form submit. Then you can use the `e.namedValues` or `e.values` properties of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to interact with the response. At this point the code will be checking the score of every answer (i.e. *Option C (from Q2) scores 2 points…*) and saving the total score in a variable. Finally you only have to write that variable into the results Sheet. To do that you can simply use [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) in the desired cell. Feel free to ask me any additional doubt.

Comment: Thanks for that Jacques. I'm going to try and get my head round what you've suggested.

Comment: Managed to get it working, thanks for your help.