# how to recode and summarize answers to a google form in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to automatize recoding and summarizing answers to a google form in apps script to display a psychological test score to a participant on form submission.
So I assume that I have to:

1. get the answers - into a vector or sth
2. recode values that are usually text (e.g. yes/no) to numbers (e.g. 1/0)
3. sum them
4. write them down somewhere, e.g. in a separate sheet
5. grab the sum and display on a "thank you" page of a form

There's this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213271/calculate-a-numeric-score-from-a-google-form-submission-using-apps-script), but unfortunately my skills too low for  now to figure it out myself.

I have the values:

```
function autoSumAnswersFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var h01 = e.values[6];
  var h02 = e.values[7];  
  (...)
  var ms06 = e.values[24];
}
```

and I'm stuck here, can't find 'recode' finction, nor reference to answer sheet.
Please give me some guidelines

Comment: If you wish to put in a little more effort and show us examples of before and after then we might be able to assist you.  Focus in on one problem at a time.  I would prefer images of your sheets and clear example of what you want.  As an alternative you could hire someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything you are trying to do can be completed without scripting but rather doing the form as a quiz. See [instructions from help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en).

I happen to have [this sample quiz](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAjGI-F2RBLwyeSl5BZ9OcDsVEUL5BIbJyWG-knmxq4zTQtw/viewform) I built for something else which does the following:

- Identifies correct and incorrect responses to questions
- Assigns point values to correct responses, that can change per question.
- Immediately after submission, users see their score (there are settings to limit if they see correct answers or just the raw score)